# How to print out failed NSURLConnection urls to find set of NSAppTransportSecurity exceptions?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsurlconnection, ios9, nsapptransportsecurity

The webviews in my apps have been getting these errors from the new iOS 9 NSAppTransportSecurity standards:

```
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
```

I don't know where this error is being generated but essentially I want to find out how to know which URL was attempted?

After that I can configure the plist appropriately.

So far I have set a breakpoint in `- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error` but this code is not called when getting the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just debugging, set the CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS environment variable to 3, e.g.

```
setenv("CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS", "3", 1);
```

at the beginning of your app, before you call anything that would potentially cause the CFNetwork framework code to load (i.e. at the beginning of **main**).  You should get the URLs in the console.

If you need to do this in a shipping app in a way that would let you debug it remotely, register an **NSURLProtocol** object globally, and in the **canInitWithRequest:** method, print the value and return NO.  That *should* happen early enough in the process that it works even with strict transport security enabled.

Example:

```
@interface MyProtocol: NSURLProtocol
@end

@implementation MyProtocol
+ (BOOL)canInitWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    NSLog(@"Request: %@\n", request); // Log it in whatever way you need.
    return NO;
}
@end

...

// Somewhere else, e.g. in applicationDidFinishLaunching:, do this:
[NSURLProtocol registerClass:[MyProtocol class]];
```

Ordering isn't guaranteed, but the failed URL is likely to be printed roughly right before the failure.

Comment: It sounds viable but I'm looking for a more low-level answer with some kind of example. Of course it doesn't have to be the full solution - just some code to get me on the right track. Also, I'm curious if this approach will catch failed image urls embedded in the urls displayed by the webviews?

Comment: An NSURLProtocol should catch any URL request by any part of the operating system, so long as it goes through NSURLConnection or NSURLSession.

Comment: Added an example of the protocol, and also added a bit about CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS environment variable, which I probably should have suggested first....  :-)

Comment: I've had some minor success so I added more specific troubleshooting steps to your first option. It's currently waiting for peer review so I will accept when approved.

Comment: Regarding the second option, how can I use this to say "this is the domain of the url that is failing". The code you provided appears to only handle printing information when initializing the object and I don't understand how this prints domain failure information.

Comment: It is an approximation intended to show you the most recent URLs (one of which was likely the failing URL) for log analysis of in-the-field failures.  If you want to know with 100% certainty which URL failued using that approach, you have to go a bit further and actually create a full protocol handler that takes the request, tweaks it in some detectable way (such as adding a header), re-issues it, refuses it when it sees the modified request (so that the normal protocol handles it), and serves as the connection/task's delegate so that it can detect the connection failure.

Comment: The extended version of that approach also requires your protocol to send challenges for authentication, etc.  It is much more complex than the code required for getting a quick approximation, which is why I didn't attempt it here.  :-)

Comment: I understand. Does `canInitWithRequest` get called as long as I register it in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`?

Comment: For NSURLConnection, yes, and by extension, for web views.  For NSURLSession, I'm not certain whether the globally registered protocols are used or not; you might have to register it as part of creating the session configuration.

Comment: Just to clarify, "...and by extension, for UIWebView views".